# Publish Android App as two different Apps on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I developed two cardgames for the android platform. The codebase is the same, so i can just set an enum to switch between the two. I dont want the user to chose one when launching the app, but publish them as two seperate apps. So what i did is set the enum for the specific game, and create two different android manifests with different icons, names and ofc different packages, so google play recognizes them as different applikation. But im not sure thats enough. So my question is, if i missed something to make them truely different? For example, when i compile the game for android with a specific manifest, the wrong app starts on my device. Not the currently compiled one but the other.

Any help on this ? Thx in advance

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Google Play only cares about the package name. Everything can be the same, but if the package name is different, then the apps are considered different.

Comment: I thought this too, but what made me think is the fact, that intelliJ starts the wrong app even tho the manifest is clearly set for the other. Ofc both apps are installed on the device, and the correct one is updated , but why does intelliJ launch the wrong one. Just wanted to make sure ill get no problems with updates later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Convert that project into library project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject), then create two new projects, with two different package names (you would have to use two package names if you want to publish two different applications on Google Play). In first project, in you main activity's `onCreate` method define enum for first card game. Make sure that that activity extends your existing activity from library project where enum is defined. Do the same for second project where you should define in `onCreate` method another enum.

Please reffer to this [page](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects) for more information.

Comment: Ok thx, that sounds like a clean solution. The documentation says i cant have my assets in the library project, so i guess i have to save them two times, one time in each project. The second thing that concerns me is the fact that im not really familar with IDEA and gradle and was really happy when i got everything gradle related setup correctly with the game engine libgdx, i use. Will this change break alot in this regard ? I think i need to add the new projects to the settings.gradle and update the main gradle file with the new projects and depend them on the android library project ?

Comment: Well, I'm not quite sure, I'm also unfamiliar with gradle. You should try it yourself.